# How to with wasm-bindgen - import js with more than one module level

Tags: wasm-bindgen

Following example https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/tree/master/examples/import_js works fine. Next step I try to import a js-module with 2 levels of modules. Let `MyClass` instead be referenced with `mylib.part1.MyClass`.

In rust wasm-bindgen file I try to import with:

```
#[wasm_bindgen(module = "/defined-in-js.js")]
extern "C" {

    type MyClass;

    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor, js_namespace = mylib.part1)]
    fn new() -> MyClass;
}
```

This gives build error:

```
error: expected `,`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:53
   |
13 |     #[wasm_bindgen(constructor, js_namespace = mylib.part1)]
   |                                                     ^
```

Is it possible to do the import in `wasm-bindgen`? Alternative some workaround solution with re-export in js without the 2 module levels (tried, but didn't manage).

Answer (score 0):

Actually documented here
https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/attributes/on-js-imports/js_namespace.html

So becomes:

```
#[wasm_bindgen(module = "/defined-in-js.js")]
extern "C" {

    #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = ["mylib", "part1"], js_name = MyClass)]
    type MyClass;

    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor, js_namespace = ["mylib", "part1"], js_name = MyClass)]
    fn new() -> MyClass;
}
```