# How to exec js code on rust with wasm-bindgen correctly

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm, yew

I'm working with rust, WASM, and yew as frontend framework. I'm building a wrapper around materialize-css, to use it on yew as dependency of reusable components.

To use some materialize-css components it's necesary initialize it. For example, to use a sidenav

```js
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, options);
  });
```

The thing is that I'm trying to run that with wasm-bindgen as described in the wasm-bindgen docs, but it doesn't work. Or maybe I do not really understand whats happening.

according to the documentation, this should work:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen( module = "/materialize/js/bin/materialize.js", js_namespace = ["M","Sidenav"] )]
extern "C" {
  fn init(el: JsValue, options: JsValue);
}

pub unsafe fn init_sidenav(el: &str, options: &str) {
    init(
        JsValue::from(document().get_element_by_id(el).expect("not found")),
        JsValue::from(options),
    );
}
```

```rust
//to use it on yew component
unsafe { materialize::sidenav::init_sidenav(self.props.el_id, &options) };
```

or this:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen( module = "/materialize/js/bin/materialize.js", js_namespace = M )]
extern "C" {
  #[wasm_bindgen]
  type Sidenav;

  #[wasm_bindgen( static_method_of = Sidenav )]
  fn init(el: JsValue, options: JsValue);
}

pub unsafe fn init_sidenav(el: &str, options: &str) {
    Sidenav::init(
        JsValue::from(document().get_element_by_id(el).expect("not found")),
        JsValue::from(options),
    );
}
```

```rust
//to use it on yew component
unsafe { materialize::sidenav::init_sidenav(self.props.el_id, &options) };
```

But neither of them works... In both cases the code compiles without problems but when executed in the browser it jumps errors.

in the first case the error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: init lib.js:1:9`

in the second case the error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: Sidenav lib.js:1:9`

honestly i dot not understand why this happens. I've been looking for some days for information in the MDN docs about WASM, and the wasm_bindgen docs, but I can't find anything that helps me.

Additionally

I'm working with --target web flag

My project structure

```
-
|Cargo.toml
|materialize/ (source of materialize-css dist)
|src/
|-components/ (wrappings of components on yew)
|-materialize/ (wasm-bindgen bindings of materialize)
|-lib.rs
|-...
...
```

Comment: many frameworks in action, so hard to tell in detail. Could look like a flavor of this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788547/how-to-with-wasm-bindgen-import-js-with-more-than-one-module-level

Comment: Hello, what did you do about this? Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Hello, what did you do about this? Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @collinsmarra I couldn't find an answer at the time. I just used an existing crate that had the abstractions I needed.

Comment: let me guess, is that `material-yew`?